# Query String variables not showing up in URL after a RedirectTo

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, url, redirect

I am trying to set up a simple  link, where the HREF points to a URL with a collection of query string parameters:
[image]

Here's the `<a>`:
[image]

Finally, after receiving the email, the URL I'm taken to after clicking is simply https://www.geha.com/enrollment.

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Hard coding the URL into the  tag.
2. Removing all that extra-ness of the  tag and make it just a super simple anchor tag (`<a href=...URL>click me</a>`).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: TRY ADDING A SLASH.....I had once faced a similar issue and it was resolved once I had added an **'/'** at the end of base URL and before query parameter as below..... geha.com/enrollment/

Comment: If you paste the wrapped URL from your inbox into [wheregoes.com](https://wheregoes.com), do you see your query string parameters?  Betting that the target page is munching the parameters and redirecting.